# How to use two prefixes "comma" "and" stem in two situations

Tags: prefixes

My native language is Dutch. We have a subtle, but useful way of combining the ingredients: Prefix (+ comma) + and + Prefix + stem. However, I do not know whether the same rules apply in the English language, *e.g.*:

"Copper-, and iron-based materials"
This means two or more materials. One or more based on copper, and at least another one based on steel, or *vice versa*.

"Copper- and iron-based materials"
This indicates multiple materials composed of copper and iron.

Thus the comma makes the difference. Furthermore, the hyphen is necessary. And last but not least: "copper-based materials and iron-based materials" does not make useful use of the rules of language.

So what are the rules?

Thank you,

Max

Comment: That is what we call the Oxford comma. Use as you wish, it's just a personal choice.

Comment: I've never heard of any such distinction. To me, _copper- and iron-based materials_ means that the statement refers to  both materials based on copper and materials based on iron.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use hyphens appropriately when listing multiple hyphenated terms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113422/how-to-use-hyphens-appropriately-when-listing-multiple-hyphenated-terms) The use of the comma is inappropriate here (though in a list, which OP does not ask about, the listing comma is used in a predictable way).

Answer (score 2):

I would say that

> *copper-and-iron-based materials*

describes materials based on *both* copper and iron, while

> *copper- and iron-based materials*

means two or more materials, some based on copper and some on iron.

Adding a comma to get

> *copper-, and iron-based materials*

wouldn't change the meaning, since *copper- and iron-based materials* already has the meaning that the comma gives it in Dutch. You wouldn't include the comma in an English sentence unless it was a list of length at least three, such as

> *copper-, iron-, and lead-based materials*.

In this case, the commas don't change the meaning.

Certainly *copper- and iron- based materials* means two or more materials, some based on copper and some on iron. See [this website](http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/marks/hyphen.htm), which says:

> **Suspended Compounds**
>
> With a series of nearly identical compounds, we sometimes delay the final term of the final term until the last instance, allowing the hyphen to act as a kind of place holder, as in
>
> *The third- and fourth-grade teachers met with the parents.
>
> Both full- and part-time employees will get raises this year.*

Comment: The OP was asking whether the presence or absence of a _comma_ after 'copper-' affected the meaning.

Comment: @Kate: Added to my answer now. I was explaining how to distinguish the two different meanings in English, but I clearly also should have said that we don't use commas like that.