# Abbreviate one noun when combined with another that has same ending

Tags: nouns, suspended-hyphen

Sorry for the probably a bit inappropriate title, I also didn't really know what to google for.

My question is, if a have a sentense like "... due to the lack of scalability and maintainability" can I get rid of the first "ability" and combine it to "... due to the lack of scal- and maintainability" like you could do in German with "... aufgrund von fehlender Skalier- und Wartbarkeit"?

Comment: You can see the related usage that _is_ allowable in English, the 'suspended hyphen' (eg at [How to use hyphens appropriately when listing multiple hyphenated terms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113422/how-to-use-hyphens-appropriately-when-listing-multiple-hyphenated-terms), though there is a tag).

Comment: Since the words are not inherently hyphenated, I don't think you can do that in English.

Comment: You really shouldn't do that for *scalability* and *maintainability*; that looks horrible. There are non-hyphenated words that you can do this for, such as [*land- and seascapes.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22land+and+seascapes%22) What's the difference? I'm not sure, but I think the difference is that *-scape* feels like a morpheme, whereas *-ability* just feels like a suffix.

Comment: I agree, but probably rather because "scal" as such is not a word. So I'll go then with the original separated version.

Comment: @Peter Shor ... _pan- and cupcakes_ and _paper- and hatchbacks_ don't work, though various forms of _paper[-] and hardbacks_ are met. I think the referents need to be very similar.

Comment: @po.pe: "due to the lack of *maintain-* and *portability*" doesn't work either. The problem is not just that *scal-* is not a word.

Answer (score -1):

No, can't do that in English. Also very wordy sentence which doesn't flow very well with such repetition.
Would it be possible to refer to the lack of ability to scale and maintenance?

Comment: Or, rather than say "Y is due to the lack of scalability and maintainability of X", say "Y happened because X cannot be scaled or maintained"? (I'd need more context to be sure, but I wonder if the subject of "is due..." is the nounification of a verb denoting an action, and it would be better to refer to the action using the verb.)