# Is it ever ac­cept­able to write slashes be­tween mul­ti­ple but sep­a­rate pre­fixes?

Tags: orthography, prefixes, slash, suspended-hyphen

For ex­am­ple, can I get away with writing *bio**/**tech­no­log­i­cal ad­vances
have made*?

Even if this is or­tho­graph­i­cally ac­cept­able in one or another kind of
writ­ten English, would it better for me to use the word *biotech­no­log­i­cal* as a single
word, or should I in­stead write *bi­o­log­i­cal and tech­no­log­i­cal
ad­vances have made*?

I haven’t been able to find any an­swers about this, whether on
this web­site or else­where.

Comment: Biotechnological  is okay. I wouldn't use it to mean biological **and** technological, but advances that are both in one. As for slashes, they usually mean on or the other, and I hate them for the wimpiness they convey.

Comment: Be apprised that this cannot possibly have anything to do with grammar or grammatical correctness: It can only be grammatically correct if it is **audible**. That's because if you can't hear it, it's not grammar. Grammar is **only** about fitting together one or both of two things: either things smaller than a word (***morphology***) or else things larger than a word  (***syntax***).

Comment: @YosefBaskin I probably shouldn't have suggested the idea of using _biotechnological_ when I did mean _biological and technological_, nevertheless thank you for your input!

Comment: I’ve edited your question into what I think it is that you are asking. Please do not hesitate to edit it yourself if there’s anything that I’ve got wrong here. But I think you may be looking for suspension hyphens.

Comment: @tchrist thanks for bettering my question, giving me a potential solution, and teaching me a new word!

Comment: See @Peter Shor's response at [How to abbreviate one noun when coupled with another that has the same ending](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/522450/abbreviate-one-noun-when-combined-with-another-that-has-same-ending) (using hyphens, eg << land- and seascapes >>). As not many examples of this device seem acceptable, it is doubtful whether many (if any) examples using dashes would be considered standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point to always remember is to make your communication unambiguous and easy to understand. This takes priority.

The slash is ill-defined in English, and thus frequently achieves confusion.

I've seen various writings where people have used the slash to mean any of "or", "and", "both", "either", "a combination of", a hyphen, etc.

I've had occasions where someone has used a slash, and I've genuinely had no idea what they meant. Despite rereading the paragraph several times, I've had to ask the writer to explain what they meant.

Using the slash slows down the reader, as they try to understand what you actually meant. Does "bio/tech­no­log­i­cal" mean "bio and technological", "bio or technological", "a combination of bio and technological", "biological and technological", "biological or technological", or something else? (When I first saw what you wrote, I thought that you meant "bio-technological", i.e. technology related to biology.)

For this reason, I would avoid using the slash except in the rare cases where its use is both widespread and obvious. (This is rare enough that I'm struggling to think of an example.)

One alternative is to use the hyphen. An example might be "uppercase and lowercase", which can be written as "upper- and lowercase". In your case, this would result in "bi­o­- and tech­no­log­i­cal". But this is somewhat forced, and thus causes the reader to have to slow down or pause, which reduces its readability. Therefore, I advise against this (although it's preferable to using a slash).

**The best solution** uses the conjunction that you mean. In your case, "bi­o­log­ical and tech­no­log­i­cal" does the job: it's unambiguous and easy to read, and it doesn't slow down the reader. It allows the reader to concentrate on the message, not on the language.