# Two compound adjectives together

Tags: compound-adjectives

If we want to use compound adjectives like "result-oriented" and "client-oriented" together to describe a person, how do we use the hyphen?

1. A result and client-oriented person.
2. A result- and client-oriented person.
3. Another way.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use hyphens appropriately when listing multiple hyphenated terms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113422/how-to-use-hyphens-appropriately-when-listing-multiple-hyphenated-terms) The specific example there was about ***ground-, water-**, and **air-based** robots*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common to use **suspended hyphens** when a single base word is used with separate, consecutive, hyphenated words that are connected by commas or "and", "or", or "to". Your number (2) is an example of this style.

> Horses were common in nineteenth- and twentieth-century literature.
>
> A result- and client-oriented person.
>
> A fire-, dog-, and soot-proof jacket.

[How to use a hyphen](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-use-a-hyphen?page=all)