# Is post-hyphenation necessary in "I am a child and adult psychologist..."?

Tags: adjectives, hyphenation

I am editing a bio for a non-writer who has written:
"I am a child and adult psychologist..."

This is awkward... it sounds like he's a child. How do I remedy this?

Is it something like: "I am a child- and adult psychologist?

Not sure what's correct here. Help, please. :)

Comment: It's their term. You probly want to use it. Why not capitalize it? That stitches it together and makes it unambiguous, as it's obviously meant to be. Plus it make them Capitalized.

Comment: "I am a child- and adult psychologist.” with the hyphen, is grammatical and not unusual. However, it is rarely used. I would go with it in your case.

Comment: Thank you to both of you for your comments. I'm going to try the hyphen version...

Comment: Only "I am a child and **an** adult psychologist" says I am six.

Comment: I am an Adult-Child psychologist.

Comment: I am a psychologist for children and adults.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Ideally there would be one convention and everyone would stick with it, but in practice people often say and write things like "I am a swimmer and runner", with a single article applying to both conjuncts.

Comment: I'm not sure that _"and adult"_ changes this at all.  The sentence _"I am a child psychologist"_ seems just as ambiguous to me.

Comment: My absolute favorite punctuation rule. *Rule 5. Never hesitate to add a hyphen if it solves a possible problem.* https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp

Comment: Horrible question.  I mean, if that was merely the opening line, then how much more carnage to inflict on it as a whole by persons pretending to be writers?

Comment: I am a psychologist working with adults and children,

Comment: Given that "child and adult" is effectively exhaustive, perhaps "I am a psychologist" is sufficient?

Comment: @NigelJ "Adult child" can refer to someone who is legally an adult but not mature (i.e. the gender neutral version of a manchild), and your phrasing makes it sound like this is their area of expertise.

Answer (score 32):

The best way to do it, I think, would be to forgo the hyphens completely and go with:

> I am a psychologist who works with children and adults.

Anything else is awkward, ambiguous, or both.

If it's necessary to emphasize that this individual works with children *and* adults (i.e., this isn't just introductory information), you could add in a 'both':

> I am a psychologist who works with both children and adults.

Comment: "I'm a tiresome pedant and I'm wondering which two children you're referring to?" 

Comment: @LamarLatrell :) I guess 'I work both with children and adults' would be better' for you tiresome pedants.

Comment: Why is "both" needed at all? Your first version seems unambiguous to me.

Answer (score 15):

Another easy solution:

> I am a **pediatric** and adult psychologist.

Since "pediatric" is an adjective, this eliminates the ambiguity.

Comment: Agreed, but it is likely that OP's client wants to use common or easier terms, which often is the preferred way of writing or speaking when it is about marketing.

Comment: "Child psychologist" is much more common than "pediatric."

Comment: Very astute johann_ka, he definitely wants to keep it (almost aggressively) plain-spoken.

Comment: Calling yourself a pediatric might not be advisable with [todays levels of stupid](https://www.theguardian.com/uk/2000/aug/30/childprotection.society). Ok, the article is 23 years old, but education hasen't become  better.

Answer (score 10):

> Is it something like: "I am a child- and adult psychologist?

To use that format you would have to be consistent:
"I am a child- and adult-psychologist."

---

**Note**
I have just found this previous question which covers the subject of hyphens in lists.

> Burchfield's 1998 edition of Fowler's Modern English Usage says under
> hyphen, listing its uses:
>
> 6 To represent a common second element in all but the last word of a
> list, e.g. *two-, three-, or four-fold.*
>
> This usage is perfectly acceptable; and in some cases it's really
> essential as Edwin Ashworth has commented:
>
> *We really have to prepare the ground- and sea-based forces.*
>
> [How to use hyphens appropriately when listing multiple hyphenated terms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113422/how-to-use-hyphens-appropriately-when-listing-multiple-hyphenated-terms)

Comment: You may want to be consistent, but adding the second hyphen isn't that. This is a suspended hyphen, and you don't want one after *adult*. A clearer example would be *micro- and macroeconomics* where there isn't even a place for the second hyphen.

Comment: Use one hyphen: child and adult -psychologist.  Then take it out because child, and adult, may be applied as adjectives.

Comment: Have you an authority licensing adding say two hyphens in such a list where there are originally zero rather than one? "I am a child psychologist." / "I am an adult psychologist." / →  "I am a child- and adult-psychologist." (There are doubtless better examples.)

Answer (score 4):

You could write this as,

> I am a child-and-adult psychologist.

This is less of a crash blossom, since it can never be misread as saying “I am a child and ....”  But this isn’t all that common.  You might prefer:

> I practice child and adult psychology.

Comment: To me that first one, apart from being unconventional and therefore open to misinterpretation, has a really weird meaning. It sounds as though the psychologist is both an adult and a child. I suppose these days with people self-identifying differently at different times that is possible but it is not what is meant.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica I personaly thought it was clear (like “salt-and-pepper hair,” “cookies-and-creme shake,” “suit-and-tie dress code”) but apparently not.

Comment: I prefer the second as clear, natural and preserving the original intent as much as possible. I tend to agree with comments about the first - it sounds like it might be some separate niche brand of psychology I've not heard of before; something to do with helping children who relate poorly to adults, or vice versa.

Comment: Great answer.  most editors in English would just change it to the first one, which is a common pattern

Answer (score 4):

Based on usage, hyphenation doesn't seem necessary. According to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20child%20and%20adult%20psychologist%22&rlz=1C1NHXL_koKR936KR936&biw=1280&bih=609&sxsrf=AJOqlzW1Bz6iTySJY4XKD6sy523TndOPlA%3A1678676532469&ei=NJIOZOubHInh2roPnrW5KA&ved=0ahUKEwjrhaSz9df9AhWJsFYBHZ5aDgUQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22a%20child%20and%20adult%20psychologist%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzoKCAAQRxDWBBCwA0oECEEYAFDwBFioDWDPFGgCcAF4AIABwwGIAdsHkgEDMC42mAEAoAEByAEFwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp), "a child and adult psychologist" seems to be the most idiomatic expression referring to a psychologist specializing in both "child psychology" and "adult psychology".

Your own suggestion and other suggestions in previous answers are simply not as idiomatic among psychologists.

It sounds "awkward" to you (because "it sounds like he's a child") because you're not familiar with the terms "child/adult psychology" and "child/adult psychologist".

Grammatically, these are not compound nouns but composite nominals, so the component parts (e.g., *child* and *adult*) can enter into relations of coordination.

Answer (score 4):

It's not awkward or ambiguous. If the writer was a child who was also an adult psychologist, not that that is a plausible situation in the first place, then they would write:

> I am a child and *an* adult psychologist.

In general a conjunction of two nouns with articles retains both articles. Since it only has one article, "a child and adult psychologist" is not a conjunction of two (countable) nouns and must be a single noun phrase, as intended.

Comment: More needless confusion.

Comment: This. The ambiguity in the grammar is resolved by pragmatics; if the speaker wanted to express "(I am a child) and (I am an adult psychologist)", _then_ they'd have to choose a different phrasing to not only resolve the ambiguity, but furthermore emphasize the intended meaning.

Answer (score 2):

It's no more confusing than saying "I am an adult psychologist" which could mean you are an adult *and* a psychologist or a psychologist who treats adults.

"Child and Adult Psychologist" also has 178k hits on Google that seems to have a similar usage. If it is commonly used like this in the industry, then I don't think it needs changing. Especially as you would have to change any other instances of "adult psychologist" to "adult-psychologist", which seems strange to me.

I think it would only cause confusion if the author was actually a child who is an adult psychologist, but then you probably wouldn't word it like this, anyway.

As for ways to get around this minor ambiguity, many other users have already given sufficient examples.

Comment: More needless confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Why not switch them around?

> "I am an adult and child psychologist"

Comment: This has the same issue: is the person a psychologist for adults?

Answer (score 0):

"I am a child and adult psychologist," without a comma after child, seems quite clear, reasonable and welcoming, to me.

Regardless, if you need to take the guy for a child, whether the comma, to over-load other bits and ways of English, then you need to see him, right away.  Sometimes, a cigar is just a cigar.

Answer (score 0):

I am both a child and adult psychologist.  …Unless, of course, the child graduated college early and is now a psychologist.

Comment: I'm not sure that adding 'both' clarifies anything here.